# Using contractions like "I'm" in text

Tags: contractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using contracted forms (“don’t”, “let’s”) in a formal text](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/using-contracted-forms-dont-lets-in-a-formal-text)
>   [Are contractions like "didn't" forbidden in written English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20275/are-contractions-like-didnt-forbidden-in-written-english?lq=1)
>   [Usage of contractions like "it's" and "that's" in textbooks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9096/usage-of-contractions-like-its-and-thats-in-textbooks)
>   [Should contractions be avoided in formal emails?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/should-contractions-be-avoided-in-formal-emails)
>   [Is it better to write without contractions? E.g. "cannot" instead of "can't"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45517/is-it-better-to-write-without-contractions-e-g-cannot-instead-of-cant?lq=1)

When I write in text, why can I not use contractions such as *I'm* instead of the full form of *I am*?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "Because your teacher says that's the style she wants".

Comment: I strongly suggest you visit our English Language Learners site and benefit from it. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Comment: Wait. It is important for you to clarify what you mean by *text*. Please edit your question to explain.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how formal you want to be. The contracted form *I’m* will be suitable for many contexts, and certainly in most forms of electronic communication. It would not, however, be appropriate in an academic paper, for example.

Comment: One of these days, however, we'll be able to use contractions in formal academic papers. I look forward to that. Maybe not for another 20 years, though.

Comment: @Bill Franke. Indeed, and it may already be happening with contrations such as _don't_.